# What is difference between np.copy and np.copy()?

Tags: numpy, copy, numpy-ndarray

what is difference between np.copy and np.copy() ? I think np.copy() creates copy of numpy array object and np.copy is attribute of the object. But when i try
`print(np.copy)` or `print(someObject.copy())` it shows message

> '<built-in method copy of numpy.ndarray object at 0x00000214E46468D0>'

or

> <function copy at 0x00000214E2B3BD30>

I'm expecting some value or object. Can you explain to me what is happening here?

edit: What is difference between

> SomeObject.copy()

and

> SomeObject.copy

?

Comment: `copy` is a function. Thats what `print` is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` just displays the function or method identity.  It doesn't run/evaluate either.

If `x` is an `numpy` array, `np.copy(x)` and `x.copy()` do the same thing.

More generally `np.copy(x)` will return an array regardless of what `x` is, while `x.copy()` uses the copy method defined for the `x class`. Those may be different.

```
In [175]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
In [176]: np.copy(x)
Out[176]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [177]: x.copy()
Out[177]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [178]: y = [1, 2, 3]
In [179]: np.copy(y)
Out[179]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [180]: y.copy()
Out[180]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I have asked wrong question. What is difference between

SomeObject.copy()

and

SomeObject.copy ?Where is SomeObject.copy used ?

Comment: `SomeObject.copy` is just the method that was defined for that class.  `SomeObject.copy()` runs that method, return a result, most likely a another object of the same class.  It is possible to define `property` that runs a method and returns a result without using the `()`, but normally that would not be called `copy`.  You may need to read more about basic python, and how to define classes.

Comment: On this `numpy` docs page, compare the `attribute` and `methods` sections, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: Can you show me situation where is `SomeObject.copy` used? (with numpy array) I understand difference between method and property. But in this case i don't undestand what is it returning.

Comment: `SomeObject.copy`, without (), is never used.  Aren't you satisfied with what your `print` showed?

Answer (score -1):

They are two different things. `print(np.copy)` copies numpy. `print(someObject.copy)` copies the object.

Comment: `np.copy` is a function in the `numpy` package.  `someObject.copy` is the copy method of  `someObject`.  That's all that the OP's prints show.  The OP is not calling either.